# How to plot latitude and longitude in map R?

Tags: r, maps, latitude-longitude, gridlines

I plotted a map of Japan and inserted gridlines using the following code:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(mapproj)

map('japan', col='black', lwd=1, ylim=c(20,50), xlim=c(120,150), mar=rep(2,4), boundary=TRUE, interior=TRUE)
map.grid(m, nx=2, ny=3, ylim=c(20,50), xlim=c(120,150), labels=TRUE, pretty=TRUE, cex=1, col='blue', lty=1)
```

and got was this:

[image]

I want the plotted latitudes to be between 20 and 50 degrees; the longitudes to be between 120 and 150 degrees - hence the ylim and xlim values.

1. Where did i go wrong? What controls the latitude and longitude limitS?
2. The rightmost longitude (149) looks cropped out. How to prevent this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The limits for `map.grid` are defined by `lim` rather than `ylim` and `xlim`.

Check with  `?map.grid`

which shows the function documentation for the `lim` argument: a vector of 4 numbers specifying limits: c(lon.low, lon.high, lat.low, lat.high). lim can also be a list with a component named range, such as the result of map, from which limits are taken.

This also resolves your longitude text cropping issue.

```r
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(mapproj)

map('japan', col='black', lwd=1, ylim=c(20,50), xlim=c(120,150), mar=rep(2,4), boundary=TRUE, interior=TRUE)
map.grid(lim = c(120, 150,  20, 50), nx=2, ny=3, labels=TRUE, pretty=TRUE, cex=1, col='blue', lty=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>